# Popup control name for settings in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm new in wp development. I don't know how to ask this correctly.
So, I want to create a popup menu for settings and other features  like on this [picture](http://vk.cc/2kIrLn)

But I can't find anythings about this. How can I do it?

Comment: It's called an app bar. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394040(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by creating an Application Bar. An example in xaml would be the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Option1" Click="Option1_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Option2" Click="Option2_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Option3" Click="Option3_Click"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

The click events being located in the code behind file of the xaml page.